# Is LINQ querying the database, making my caching useless?

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, linq, nopcommerce

So I have some code like this:

```
var attribute = _genericAttributeService
    .GetAttributesForEntity(_workContext.CurrentCustomer.Id, "Customer")
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "CompareProducts");
```

The `GetAttributesForEntity` looks like this:

```
public virtual IList<GenericAttribute> GetAttributesForEntity(int entityId, string keyGroup)
{
    return _cacheManager.Get(string.Format(GENERICATTRIBUTE_KEY, entityId, keyGroup), () =>
    {
        var query = from ga in _genericAttributeRepository.Table
                            where ga.EntityId == entityId &&
                            ga.KeyGroup == keyGroup
                            select ga;
        var attributes = query.ToList();
        return attributes;
    });
}
```

So it's using caching to reduce db queries.

Is the `FirstOrDefault()` now querying the returned list, or is another database query made?
Would be good to know exactly what's happening here.

Comment: If we don't know what _cacheManager is we have no way of knowing. You can always [profile the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to see what is happening.

Comment: What @Crowcoder said. Please add code for the CacheManager or atleast a link to the package.

Comment: @Crowcoder cachemanager is per request caching

Comment: A cache in front of another cache is usually useless.  Sometimes even counterproductive.

Comment: @RickJames what is the second cache? I only see the per request cache manager _cacheManager

Comment: The database engine does caching -- mostly to avoid extra I/O, which is usually the main performance hit.

Comment: as in execution plans? through implementing caching we have been able to solve problems with db locking, and the performance impact is remarkable too. Really noticible.

Comment: While you might be caching all the attributes for an entity, I would cache a dictionary and change the api to query that dictionary. Scanning an entire list to look for one item feels a little expensive.

Comment: Your sample shows that you are querying just List, so it is not another db request. Usually `IQueryable` initiates db request after `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the FirstOrDefault() now querying the returned list, or is another
> database query made?

Short answer:

FirstOrDefault will query the cached list.

Long answer:

_cacheManager will use the provided arguments `(entityId, keyGroup)` to retrieve the list from the cache.

If the element is not in the cache, it will execute the lambda to retrieve the data from the database and will store the results with key `(entityId, keyGroup)`.

It will store the complete `List<>`. Pay attention to the statement:

```
var attributes = query.ToList();
```

So, if you repeat a call to `GetAttributesForEntity`, using the same parameters, you will get the stored results.

*Note: NopCommerce implements different cache levels, and cache invalidation procedures, which I will not dive into at this moment.*

Comment: Hi Marco thanks for confirming, I wasn't sure :)
I realize these queries can be improved anyway which I'm going to work on